# How to clear tags from a string with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

```
<div id="mydiv">
    <p>
        <b><a href="mypage.html">This is an example<a>.</b>
        <br>
        This is another example.
    </p>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var mystr = document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML;
    .....
</script>
```

I want to clear all tags, and get the salt text,

```
mystr = "This is an example this is another example.";
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using `innerText` and `textContent`:

```
var element = document.getElementById('mydiv');
var mystr = element.innerText || element.textContent;
```

- [`innerText`](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_html.html#t04) is supported by all browsers but FF
- [`textContent`](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_html.html#t07) is supported by all browsers but IE

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/yPj3a/1/)

I just saw that the string will still contain line breaks. You might want to remove them with [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

```
mystr = mystr.replace(/\n/g, "");
```

**Update:**

As [@Šime Vidas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/425275/sime-vidas) points out in his comment, it seems you have to handle the whites spaces a bit differently  to fix the string in IE:

```
mystr = mystr.replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
```

Comment: The replace() will only replace one line-break - see here: http://jsfiddle.net/yPj3a/4/

Comment: @Sime: Ah right... I forgot that JavaScript's `replace` method works.... differently ;) Thanks and fixed.

Comment: `replace(/\n/g, '')` has browser compatibility issues. This: `replace(/\s+/g, ' ')` works cross-browser, see here: http://jsfiddle.net/yPj3a/8/

Comment: @Sime: Thanks :) (I have no IE to test though...)

Comment: From my testing `\s+` will catch all white-space including line breaks which makes it the ultimate solution. `\n` is therefore not needed.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a different approach - remove the tags using replace with a regular expression:

```
document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML.replace(/\n|<.*?>/g,'')
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KbxUN/)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
document.getElementById('mydiv').innerText || document.getElementById('mydiv').textContent;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through all childs and read `.innerText` from them. Then you can easily concatenate the text from each child and get all the text without tags.