# jquery tablesorter custom parser - innerHTML vs. innerText

Tags: internet-explorer, jquery-plugins, innerhtml, tablesorter, innertext

I'm using tablesorter and trying to create custom sort parsers - the parsers work great in Firefox, but fail entirely in Internet Explorer. Why do the parsers work in one, but not the other??

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  The site is designed for a question and answer format.  You're just stating a solution here.  The information may be valuable, so you probably should create a question.  And, then add this as your answer.

Comment: Ok, I'll edit my submission into a better question/answer format.  I wanted to post an answer, but it won't let me for the first 7 hours.  Thanks, bobs.

Answer (score 1):

In my [fork of tablesorter](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter), I also found that using `textContent` was much faster in IE9 (and of course all other modern browsers), so I modified the [internal coding](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/blob/master/js/jquery.tablesorter.js#L128-L132) to automatically do this:

```
if (config.supportsTextContent) {
    text = node.textContent; // newer browsers support this
} else {
    text = $(node).text();
}
```

I've also made some other improvements to the [`textExtraction` option](http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/#textextraction) which allows you to get the `cellIndex` and/or add a function for a specific column.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a custom parser, tablesorter uses this function:
getElementText(config, node)

getElementText will try to grab text from table cells - but some of the table cells may include html tags as well.  Cell [td] tags which contain other html tags (like [span] or [img]) cause problems for IE, because the function simply grabs ALL of the cell's innerHTML (extraneous tags included) instead of just the IE supported innerText.

The getElementText function works great in Firefox because the function grabs the Firefox supported (self-explanatory) textContent, ignoring the html tags within the cell.  See related question: [jQuery tablesorter: custom html image tag sorter/parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6618372/jquery-tablesorter-custom-html-image-tag-sorter-parser)

The best way to resolve this issue is to make tablesorter grab the cell text properly in the first place, based on what is supported by the browser, innerText or textContent.  Kling's answer helped set me on the right path:
[How to clear tags from a string with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4898723/how-to-clear-tags-from-a-string-with-javascript)

Open the tablesorter.js file and modify the portion of getElementText(config, node) shown below. I've also submitted this suggestion to the tablesorter author.

**Replace innerHTML with innerText:**

```
if (config.supportsTextContent) {
    text = node.textContent;
} else {
    if (node.childNodes[0] && node.childNodes[0].hasChildNodes()) {
        text = node.childNodes[0].innerText;
    } else {
        text = node.innerText;
    }
}
```

Comment: Per tablesorter's author, he is aware of the this issue, but stated it is by design - sometimes parsers are used to sort HTML elements such as checkboxes, etc.